# hacer estilo Slider en una aplicación de escritorio usando c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un inventario, pero al momento de que el programa este cargando, deseo poner un tipo "slider" en la aplicación.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de a lo que te refieres? no se que quieres decir con "slider"

Comment: Como en las paginas web, que traen una mini-galerias de imagenes que van cambiando automaticamente.

Comment: Algo [así](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808930/Animated-Image-Slide-Show)?

Comment: Exactamente amigo, algo parecido, pero que vaya cambiando automáticamente.

Comment: [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23082/A-Simple-Image-Slide-Show) otro ejemplo. Si en lugar de por botones como ahi quieres que sea automatico, usa simplemente un timer que llame al boton "next" y ya esta

Comment: Perfecto amigo, lo pondré a prueba y muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el componente que tiene `WPF` en `winform`

[Carousel XAML Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/carousel)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto usaras el `ElementHost`

[Tutorial: Hospedar un control compuesto de WPF en formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]